# Cannot execute .sql file from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have an assignment which involves creating a database from a .sql file. When trying to execute the file in Visual Studio a window pops up prompting me to enter Server name (where I enter my IP), username and password, but when I press "connect", it gives me following error:
[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you installed SQL Server or attached the database if you're using LocalDB?

Comment: This might sound a bit dumb: I need additional software to execute .sql files? I did attach the local DB

Comment: You need SQL Server installed, yes. That isn't additional software, what SQL is run against. SQL is used to run code against an RDBMS. If you don't have an RDBMS, you can't run SQL.

Comment: Are you connecting to a remote server or try accessing the local machine? What edition of SQL Server are you using? Is the SQL server started? If it's a local machine, is `named pipes` enabled (this is the communication channel the client tries). If it's a remote machine, `named pipes` communication won't work. You must use TCP/IP

Comment: During installation of Visual Studio you can install LocalDB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017